# Intuit Partner Platform example application for .NET

Tags: .net, intuit-partner-platform

I want install Intuit Partner Platform example application for .NET from [this](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_DevKits_for_Intuit_Partner_Platform/Sample_Apps/.NET_Sample_App_for_AggCat_Services/0010_Creating_the_App). I did all steps from this url. But i don't know where i can find FileEncryptionKey for web.config. Can anybody help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key length has to be 192 bits for Triple DES.  Here is an example.

```
<add key="FileEncryptionKey" value="9aA2dD0fZ3Dab4126d7i5643"/>
```

Comment: It can be any string with length 24, can it?

Comment: For the encoding used in the sample application, yes.